# Speech Recognition in Tizen with React

Tags: reactjs, speech-recognition, tizen, tizen-web-app

I'm trying to do a simple Voice to Text conversion on a React App, that will be running on a Tizen Device.

Samsung informed me that these Tizen devices do not support `window.SpeechRecognition`.

They have a Speech Synthesizer that could be used for TTS but since Speech Recognition is not directly supported, I don't think I can use something like [Artyom.js](https://sdkcarlos.github.io/sites/artyom.html).

Is there any JS Library I could use in this instance?

Comment: Hello, have you checked this page? If your device is Samsung TV, it could be helpful. https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/guides/fundamentals/text-to-speech.html

Comment: @LunchBasketball TTS is fine. I need to convert voice input into text.